# Mods shouldn't close a question with 1 single vote as unclear without giving a chance to the OP to clarify the question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

The question
[Why do flights sometimes share the same flight numbers?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/163124/1810) was closed by one moderator as unclear. The question hadn't received any other close vote.. No comment were left by the moderator. That shouldn't be happening as 1. This doesn't give the OP a chance to keep the question open 2. The OP doesn't understand what was unclear in the moderator's mind 3. This was a hot network question and closing the question removed it from the hot network question list, thereby losing potential answers.

I'd also note that the question hadn't received in any unanswered question in the comment section, and that the question received two clear answers by the time the question was closed.

Please moderate more mindfully.

Comment: while you note "that the question received two clear answers by the time the question was closed.", I'd note that they seem to be answering entirely different questions from each other, and neither of them is the question I thought you were asking.

Comment: @ChrisH they answer the same question but give two different reasons, which I've already stated in two comments.

Comment: Yes you have stated that. I disagree, and I'm demonstrably not the only one.

Comment: @ChrisH anyway that doesn't matter, the issue is that one mod shouldn't close a question by themselves without leaving (or someone else) some form of question in the comment.

Comment: The comment is in the standard text which is placed at closing. No need to post an extra message for someone who has been around on TSE for quite a while. (Beginners do sometimes get help, you should not need that anymore.)

Comment: @Willeke the standard message is way too vague: it doesn't say why the mod thinks is unclear.

Answer (score 5):

You had been ask for more details, more than 12 hours later there were still no details.
But that is not the point, questions get closed for 'lack of details' all the time, often within seconds from first time reading.

Closure for lack of details does give OP time to edit, it is a usual way to handle questions.

We should not have to guess what is meant nor search for flights on a number alone. Date and airports should be given at least.

Mods have the duty to keep the quality of the site high. So close unclear questions. (It should not yet have been in the hot questions queue, but I think that closing does not take the question from that list.)

Comment: "You had been ask for more details" -> by whom? Questions with 2 answers + HNQ don't typically get closed for 'lack of details all the time within seconds from first time reading.

Comment: I think the question behind this question is 'why was this question closed' and you will get better (and more friendly) responses when you ask that in the chatroom rather than as a Meta question. Those should be reserved for more important problems.

Comment: No the question is why 1 mod closes the question without first asking for clarification in the comment section

Comment: 12 hours isn't enough. Please give users a reasonable amount of time next time.

Comment: @user1271772, you can edit when closed and after editing the question can and often will be re-opened. On the other hand, onclear questions get messed up answers and should be closed before answers are given if possible.

Comment: Franck has 400k network-wide reputation. I think he knows how to ask a question. The original version and newest version are the same, except the new version has the same thing written again with different words. The question got a truly excellent and thorough answer within 40 minutes and became an HNQ before being closed. The person who answered didn't seem to find the original question unclear. I didn't find it unclear. Perhaps you haven't flown enough to know whether or not the question was clear, which is why all sites require 3-5 close voters, or 1 expert (gold badge holder on the tag).